# how to create a new dictionary using a pre-existing list, assigning values to the items in the list

Tags: python, list

I have a list of items, and now I need to assign some values to each items of that list and store all the items along with their respective values in a new dictionary

I tried to create a blank dictionary at first , then I tried to insert values using for loop , is that ok , I don't know I'm just confused

Comment: Show us what you tried

Comment: That sounds fine. It is important to write clear code that you fully understand. You only need to think about faster ways to do things when you have large amounts of data. A for loop is perfectly acceptable. As you move forward you will come across other ways such as using dictionary comprehension.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe there are faster and smart ways to do that, but in your case you reached your goal, so of course it is OK.